# Where can I find up-to-date browser compatibility guides?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

Let me start by saying I really appreciate the work done at [QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org) but in recent experience the content seems a bit dated.

- Some pages haven't been updated from anywhere between 6months and a year.
- Compatibility tables still only show chrome at version 5.0 (W3C DOM Compatibility) or 1.0 (Event compatibility tables)

In cases where content seems a bit dated I generally refer to [Sitepoint's References](http://reference.sitepoint.com), but their HTML and Javascript Reference pages are also a bit our of date.

What compatibility reference guides do you all use?

**update**

I'm aware of sites like [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com), which are invaluable reference new feature support like new JS API libraries and CSS3 support. However I'm more interested in things like supported attributes (bad example I admit) and browser events. The more vanilla stuff.

And please, noone mention w3schools (see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) why you should never use this site)

Comment: If all else fails you can count on Internet Explorer making your life as a developer harder.

Comment: This is a real difficulty in the new world of rapid browser releases.  Looking forward to seeing the answers here.

Comment: This actually came up, believe it not, trying to determine cross browser support for window.onload

Comment: @Nick, actually Amaya-the-reference-browser.

Comment: @Free I was only including IE,Opera,Chrome,Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: Well, that's not quite so new, but it would be useful to know. Might be worth looking at the jQuery source to see how they deal with onload: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js

Comment: @calvinf, I agree in this case, but I'm gearing the question to be more generic as it would appeal to a larger audience. There are many more cases of this kind of lack in information. Plus there are no guarantees what you would be looking for is in the jQuery source, i.e. I'm more interested in the body.onload rather then dom load complete (`ready()`) which are two very different things.

Comment: @xzyfer Actually, I meant search the jquery source for window.onload, there's a couple interesting bits in there.

Answer (score 8):

http://caniuse.com is quite good and (provided you use the correct keywords) has good search functionality as well.

In addition to the above you might be interested in the ES5 compatibility tables that [Kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) maintains at http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

*update*
In the meantime there is also the [ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) compat table. Quite red for now (9/2014) admittedly, but getting more and more useful.

Comment: I use this as well, but it's targeted new features like new JS API libraries and CSS3 support. I'm more interested in things like supported attributes and browser events. The more vanilla stuff.

Comment: So more geared towards html than css and js?

Comment: Pretty much what quirks mode, just with more current info. If they include new feature support great! This actually came up, believe it not, trying to determine cross browser support for window.onload where quirks mode notes "I haven’t tested the load and unload events yet; they’ll be added to the table later on." - this page was last updated over a year ago.

Comment: He's looking for generic event and attribute support information and not just bleeding-edge HTML5, CSS3, and DOM feature support.

Answer (score 2):

I trust **Quirksmode**, have you any idea how many tests PPK runs? It's not that it's outdated (yet!) it's that CSS support (and Browser uptake) has reached a new level, trust me you will appreciate the experience if you have to support an older browser.

Not every FF or Opera user updates quickly anymore which is what could be relied on for a while!  - so yes you're right to question the findings. personally I look for recent sites too but I don't "trust" them nearly as much as the older and even then I tend to test for myself.

There's no replacement for experience IMO often these guys can "guess" at what may be the problem based on their past experience even if the so called "bug" or unexpected display is new to them in that context.

I have a "bug" report detailed on PPK's site -  yea it and me are old -  but only last week I got asked about something (seemingly unrelated) which turned out to be the same thing and have the same solution, it's IE7 related so will be with us for a while yet. (I see caniuse thinks that's old eeek!) - I am completely in awe of these guys who have kept up these sites for so long, if you can reverse engineer the bugs you get to understand the browsers.. that will never fail you as long as the browsers are on the go - their render engines don't usually change all that much between versions!

but then again this is a new era of Browser wars so who knows what will happen :)

Comment: Disagree w/ your point about FF users updating slowly. FF4 has more than 11 million downloads in just over a day. http://glow.mozilla.org/

Comment: I agree with you, and I use quirks mode somewhat religiously. This actually came up, believe it not, trying to determine cross browser support for window.onload where quirks mode notes "I haven’t tested the load and unload events yet; they’ll be added to the table later on." - this page was last updated over a year ago.

Comment: @calvinF you can disagree that is your right, but I've been religious FF user since NN days (I didn't admit it back then of course ;)), I do not update instantly anymore -  my prefs are set and updates have been known to break them.. so I backup and wait, - the new stats on updates are impressive, but every user that updates.. that's another browser version to have to support ..user view not a developer view btw

Comment: @xyfer.. yes I think I see where you're at, but there comes a point when you will know better than any chart if that's what you're after, it's impossible now for any one site to keep up with every nuance

Comment: @clairesuzy true, users have a different view of it. I think Chrome does the best job making sure things don't break between versions.

Comment: true @calvinf.. that's cos they're the "new kid" and obviously have a lot to lose being as who they are.. all of this is of course superficial as I think it will come back to what you (a user) wants to do with your browser (like your phone)if you want the app that Chrome supports then  that will be the choice, or if it's Apple app then Safari might be your choice, in an everyday commercial world I can't see anything other than IE making it - it's a very different landscape than it was hence me saying that no one site will be a "cover all" any more

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this big javascript compatibility table
http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/de/home/
Its very big, but checks at the moment only for existenz of javascript properties.